# Javascript: Get highest possible UTF8 character

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I need to get the highest possible UTF8 character for a prefix search.

I have a data set like this:

```
A
Ba
Bf
C
```

Now I can do a prefix search by specifying start and end values:

```
Start: B
End: B* where * should be the highest possible UTF8 character.
```

How can I get this programatically using Javascript?

Edit: Here is a better example:

I need to send this prefix to a JSON RPC API. So I can't do the actual comparison in JS.

But if I wanted to mach both strings starting with B, I would send

```
Start: B 
End: B?
```

where ? is the biggest possible UTF8 character.

If it was ASCII, I could do `"B" + String.fromCharCode(255)`, but this is just for ASCII. My strings are in UTF8, in which case this wouldn't match all possible strings starting with B.

Comment: Is it `C` or `f` in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "prefix search"? Do you want to process only items that start with specific prefix? Doesn't `input.substr(0, prefix.length) == prefix` cover it (with your example, `input.substr(0, 1) == 'B'`)?

Comment: I need to send this prefix to a JSON RPC API. So I can't do the actual comparison in JS. But if I wanted to mach both strings starting with B, I would send

Start: B
End: B? where ? is the biggest possible UTF8 character.

If it was ASCII, I could do "B" + String.fromCharCode(255), but this is just for ASCII. My strings are in UTF8, in which case this wouldn't match all possible strings starting with B.

Comment: Can't you send `start=B, end=C` and disregard the final result if it is `C`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a range, you can use `\uffff`.

```
MyRange("foo", "foo\uffff")
```

Will find everything that starts with `foo`.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your code, you might not need the actual highest UTF8 code point.

```
if ((input >= 'B') && (input < 'C')) { ... }
```

could do the trick for you.

Comment: Where is the programmatic part to get `'B'` and `'C'` ? I might be misunderstanding a lot here...

Comment: How would I know? That would depend on OP's application logic outside of the problem in question.

Answer (score 2):

```
const maximumCodePoint = String.fromCodePoint(0x10ffff)

> String.fromCodePoint(0x10ffff + 1)
RangeError: Invalid code point 1114112
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice proof with +1 giving RangeError. The Wikipedia article on UTF-8 also lists U+10ffff as the "Last Code Point" for 4 byte code points: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You can do UTF code point comparison of string beginnings in JavaScript by using the [`>` comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). So you could use

```
search >= "B" && search < "C"
```

, but a simple

```
search.test(/^B.*/)
```

or

```
search.charAt(0) == "B"
```

should do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you want:

```
var datas = [
    'A',
    'Bf',
    'Ba',
    'C'
];

// Create an array with char codes prefixed with "B" but it returns
// for the second string. For example, for B*, it returns the char code of *.
var datasB = datas.map( function( data ) {
    if ( data.charAt( 0 ) === 'B' ) {
        return data.substr( 1 ).charCodeAt( 0 );
    }
} ).filter( Boolean );
// The `filter( Boolean )` removes the falsy values (undefined)

// This technique is very efficient to get the maximum value of an array
var max = Math.max.apply( Math, datasB );
```

Inspiration from [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/) for the technique to get the max value of an array.